# C# задачки и интересности

Tags: c#

Недавно наткунлся на интересные [задачки на C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20140503015922/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaidar/archive/2008/10/26/9017096.aspx). Стало невероятно увлекательным занятием их разгадывать без использования сред программирования. Может кто знает ещё подобные задачки или их сборники?

- Задачи на поведение компиляции и исполнения
- Задачи на алгоритмы и структуры данных используя исключительные особенности языка
- Нестандартные пути решения стандартных задач используя исключительные особенности языка
- Различные однострочники
- Ленивые вычисления
- Написание интересностей присутсвующих в других языках
- Прочее

**ПРИМЕР#1:**
если станет интересно приведу ещё парочку

```
int i = myString.To<int>();
```

простейший extension method, а как здорово выглядит=)

```
public static T To<T>(this IConvertible obj)
{
  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
}
```

источник [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow)

**ПРИМЕР#2:**

список в функциональном стиле:

```
public class FuncList<T> { 
   public FuncList() {                                        
      IsEmpty = true; 
   } 
   public FuncList(T head, FuncList<T> tail) {                
      IsEmpty = false; 
      Head = head; 
      Tail = tail; 
   } 
   public bool IsEmpty { get; private set; }                  
   public T Head { get; private set; }                       
   public FuncList<T> Tail { get; private set; }             
} 
 
public static class FuncList {                               
    public static FuncList<T> Empty<T>() { 
        return new FuncList<T>(); 
    } 
    public static FuncList<T> Cons<T>(T head, FuncList<T> tail) { 
        return new FuncList<T>(head, tail); 
    } 
}
```

рекурсивные создание, подсчёт суммы и произведения:

```
var list = FuncList.Cons(1, FuncList.Cons(2, FuncList.Cons(3,       
    FuncList.Cons(4, FuncList.Cons(5, FuncList.Empty<int>()))))); 
    

int SumList(FuncList<int> numbers) { 
   return numbers.IsEmpty ? 0 :                                    
      numbers.Head + SumList(numbers.Tail);                         
} 

int MultiplyList(FuncList<int> numbers) { 
   if (numbers.IsEmpty) return 1;                            
   else return numbers.Head * MultiplyList(numbers.Tail);   
}
```

источник `Tomas Petricek, Jon Skeet - Functional Programming for the Real World`

P.S. жду критики, отзывов, оценок

Comment: Могу от себя добавить только "задачи для хакеров". Там общие задачи, но на логику.

Comment: @Goldy , а сылочку можно?

Comment: <a href="http://www.booksgid.com/entertainment_hobby/4340-.html">Вот</a>

Comment: > простейший extension method, а как здорово выглядит=)
> 
>     int i = myString.To<int>();

Каждый вызов такого метода скрывает внутри себя множественный boxing/unboxing.
Выглядит здорово, но не годится для случаев, когда важна производительность.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В этом [блоге](http://netpl.blogspot.com/search/label/Puzzle) 22 задачки, правда уже не обновляется. Есть как простые так и посложнее.

Еще [один](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html) популярный сборник.

Comment: очень даже интересно, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно аналогичный расширяющий метод для строго типизированного доступа к сервисам:

```
public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
  return (T)provider.GetService(typeof(T));
}
```